# Intellij Idea project checkout

Tags: git, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Okay, so I checked out a Git project into Intellij via VCS - Checkout from Version Control - Git. I see the code checked out and repository cloned at the Parent Directory under the Directory name I give.

However, when I open this project in Intellij, it does not show up connected to Git, so I cannot do an update or Check in etc. Is there any way I can connect my workspace to Git for having change control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File > Settings > Version Control
```

Also make sure you have GIT plugin enabled in intellij.

Comment: Ahh, got it. I selected the current Git candidate and now it is connected. WHy do we have to manually do this, though? Since I cloned it using Intellij Version Control (not Command line), should Intellij not implicitly be attached to Git?